# How can I fix SPARQL Query Error "Expected on of.." in Protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I am trying to execute a SPARQL query in Protege, however, no matter how i change the syntax i keep encountering this error:
[image]
This thing it highlights is a data property.

Also, my SPARQL Query window isn't working, so I'm using Snap SPARQL Query. I updated my plugins, my ontology is consistent, so I am genuinely confused at what is wrong. Would be so grateful if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: check your prefix declaration, I'm sure either a trailing `#` or `/` is missing for prefix `classical_music:` - it depends on the namespace you defined in your ontology.

Answer (score 1):

Add `/` to a prefix declaration.